# Ghost incrementing INT field in MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, cron, yii, prado

Very strange things happening in phpMyAdmin (mySQL)....

**The Situation:**
I have a table with only one field that holds an INT value called 'count'. count was originally set to 0. A cron job calls a php script every hour which increments 'count' by one `(SET count = count + 1)`.

**The Problem**:
The problem can be observed when I open the table in phpMyAdmin, and then immediately refresh the browser: I can see that 'count' has been incremented like 20 times in under a second. Leaving it alone for a minute and then refreshing the browser again shows that it's been incremented hundreds of more times! Is some endless loop somewhere calling my cron job and incrementing 'count'? (Don't think so because I updated crob php script to email me when its called, and I'm getting no calls...)

Has anything like this ever happened to anyone?

**The CRON String:**

```
*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /home/account_name/cron/cron.php test
```

**The php Script:**

```
<?php

class TestCommand extends CConsoleCommand {
    private $connection;

    public function run($args) {
        // Increment counter
        $this->connection=Yii::app()->db;
        $sql="UPDATE count_converts SET count=count+1 WHERE id=1";
        $command=$this->connection->createCommand($sql);
        $command->execute();
    }
 }

?>
```

**UPDATE:**
Mystery solved: Found out this was due to a bad nested for loop somewhere else (both loops used $i)...

Comment: can you please post your cron string?

Comment: Code or it didn't happen

Comment: Just because the script isn't mailing you doesn't mean it's not running - it could be bailing out/dieing before it reaches the email stage.

Comment: @Marc B -- I put the mail command at the very top of the php script assuming that the mailer would execute even if the following script fails. [UPDATE] just to be 100% SURE, I removed everything from the php script (even the db updater) and count is still incrementing like crazy...on VPS by the way

Comment: The full MySQL query please. The PHP script please.

Comment: @Phill Pafford I think the OP has a <br /> in the cron string

Comment: do a `show processlist` in mysql, to see what other connections are open.

Comment: fwiw - the cron entry says "run once every 15 minutes", not "once an hour".

Comment: @Deep I really hope not but you could be correct

Comment: how are you instantiating the class?

Comment: BTW you're missing the closing bracket in your class, hopefully another grammar and not a syntax error

Comment: If it's not the script being run over and over, my suspicion would be triggers gone wild.

Comment: @Phill Pafford the class is initiated by the console (its a Yii framework console app)

Comment: You still need something like: $tc = new TestCommand(); $tc->run($args);

Comment: @Phill Pafforf seems like run is a standard function that gets called when running a Yii console app. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.console Eric can you please post the cron.php code?

Comment: Looking over the documentation you provided I'm not sure you are implementing/executing this properly. I know Yii uses a AutoLoader which in turn could be calling and executing your script multiple times. I think you might need some specialized help from the community: http://www.yiiframework.com/community/ best of luck and post back if you find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why id there a <br /> and a line break in your cron string? Change it to

*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /home/account_name/cron/cron.php test

Comment: Thanks for answer. However, the cron job gets called with no problems. (There is no actual line break in the real cron string -- my bad text formatting.)

Comment: @Eric what was this the real issue?